# Azure DevOps - Missing dropdown options for rules

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to create a rule for a child ticket where when the field for T-Shirt Sizing is completed, it triggers the field for "original estimate" to change to the corresponding value of the T-Shirt size. When I try to set up the rule, there is no option to choose the field for T-Shirt sizing or original estimate, even though I have included it in the work item template.

What am I missing?

[image: rules screen]

Tried this in Process > Rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to Organization Settings -> Process -> Find your target inherited process.
[image]

Click your work item type from the list, then you will see the layout of your work item. Please check if you can see your target field. For example, as shown follow:
[image]

In my test, both my custom field and original estimate field can be found in the drop-down box.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I realized I hadn't created the field in all my child templates and that's why it wasn't an option to choose.